# Не обязательно или необязательно?

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в предложении "Не обязательно иметь крылья, чтобы летать" "не обязательно" пишется слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом предложении мы отрицаем тезис о том, что *"обязательно иметь крылья, чтобы летать"*, поэтому частицу **"не"** пишем отдельно.

Если бы мы имели в виду, что *"иметь крылья"* - это проявление необязательности, мы бы написали *"необязательно иметь крылья"*, но здесь явно не этот случай.

Answer (score 2):

**Не обязательно иметь крылья, чтобы летать.**

В зависимости от контекста возможно слитное или раздельное написание (второе - при подчеркивании отрицания либо при противопоставлении). На мой взгляд, у вас именно отрицание общепринятого представления о том, что крылья иметь обязательно, поэтому я бы написал раздельно. Хотя и слитное написание не будет ошибкой.

> [НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20&all=x), нареч. 1. к Необязательный (3 зн.). Смежники вели себя крайне н. 
>   2. в функц. сказ. О том, что не является обязательным, непременным; нет необходимости. Вам н. приезжать самому. Ему н. лечиться в санатории. Н., чтобы об этом все знали.

Подборка ответов справочной службы портала Грамота:

> Вопрос № 298614
>   Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, слитно или раздельно нужно писат ь: необязательно или не обязательно?
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   В зависимости от контекста возможно слитное или раздельное написание 
>   (второе - при подчеркивании отрицания либо при противопоставлении).
>
> Вопрос № 297489
>   Как правильно: НЕ ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО или НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО? В случае: "фаст-фуд – это необязательно вредно, но обязательно вкусно".
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Возможны оба способа написания.
>
> Вопрос № 286833
>   Здравствуйте! Объясните, пожалуйста, разницу. Эту книгу читать не обязательно. Для этого необязательно уезжать так далеко. Правильно ли все написано? И как понять, когда писать "не обязательно", а когда - "необязательно"? Спасибо!
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   В обоих примерах возможно и слитное, и раздельное написание. Раздельное написание подчеркивает отрицание.
>
> Вопрос № 285948
>   Как расставить знаки препинания в предложении "Признаться в своей ошибке перед самим собой ( не обязательно делать это публично: тогда это либо стыдно, либо - рисовка) не всегда легко.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Корректная пунктуация: Признаться в своей ошибке перед самим собой (необязательно делать это публично: тогда это либо стыдно, либо рисовка) не всегда легко.
>
> Вопрос № 276884
>   Подскажите, пожалуйста, как пишется слово "необязательно" или "не обязательно" в предложении "Быть членом партии (не) обязательно".
>   Спасибо.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Не обязательно в значении сказуемого пишется раздельно: Быть членом партии не обязательно.
>
> Вопрос № 260179
>   Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать "необязательно" (раздельно или вместе) в следующем предложении (и почему):
>   Если для пункта [Режим IS] задано значение [Выкл.], задавать параметры конвертера необязательно.
>   Александра 
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Вы написали верно.

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь:

Слова категории состояния на -о (так называемые предикативные наречия) пишутся с частицей ***не*** **слитно при утверждении**: *нетрудно видеть* и **раздельно** **при отрицании**: *не трудно видеть* (смысл обычно устанавливается самим пишущим).

В Вашем случае оба варианта написания возможны.