# Как подчеркнуть отрицание при выборе формы написания НЕ?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Этот вопрос возник при чтении ответа Грамоты.ру, который цитируется в ответе [Не обязательно или необязательно?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447009/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE)

> Вопрос № 298614 Необязательно или не обязательно?
>
> В зависимости от контекста возможно слитное или раздельное написание
>   **(второе – при подчеркивании отрицания** либо при противопоставлении).

**Что имеется в виду под подчеркиванием?** Раздельное написание — это уже подчеркивание или речь идет об особом чтении, о выделении голосом?

Можно ли подчеркнуть это слово в предложении другой структуры:  *Чтобы летать, иметь крылья не обязательно.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ответе Грамоты речь о том, как писать, значит о подчеркивании на письме (путем раздельного написания). Следующий вопрос: как это следует читать. По-моему, так:  *Чтобы летать, иметь крылья нЕ {пауза} обязательно.*

Comment: А удобно так читать? Это естественная пауза, да еще в предложении такой структуры? Может быть, здесь следует использовать слитную форму письма, а при желании написать НЕ раздельно наречие нужно вынести в начало предложения?

Comment: Наверно, так, как Вы предлагаете, лучше, но это необязательно (или не обязательно). Из ответов Грамоты: "Быть членом партии не обязательно".

Comment: Мне это предложение не кажется естественным, но   здесь всё-таки возможна интонационная пауза, и раздельное написание (с подчеркиванием) не исключается. Но в заданном предложении даже интонационную паузу сложно сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Давайте попробуем так:

***Чтобы летать, иметь крылья не(-) обязательно***. - Обязательно? Нет (-). ОТРИЦАНИЕ подчёркивается, то есть очень чётко выражено, категорично. Пишем НЕ раздельно.

***Чтобы летать, иметь крылья необязательно.*** = Чтобы летать, можно и не иметь крылья. - То есть 50 на 50: можно иметь, можно не иметь... Отрицание не такое категоричное: необязательно=возможно (+) отсутствие обязательности.  - УТВЕРЖДЕНИЕ. Пишем НЕ слитно.

Comment: Я понимаю смысл подчеркнутого отрицания. Вопрос о том, как подчеркивание (выделение) обозначить в письменной и устной речи.

Comment: В письменной - раздельным написанием, в устной - ударением на НЕ.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ.